# How to restrict wireless networks seen on my ubuntu machines

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless, router

I have 2 wireless routers (ground floor - c1, first floor - c2). I would like the Ubuntu machines in my LAN to see only the above wireless routers (c1, c2) and not routers outside my building (say the adjacent building). What should I do in order to achieve this?

Comment: Rpj same issue right but you are asking here more particularly.

Comment: Rpj , here eventhough we can answer windows part you shouldnt ask here. edit your question and remove that windows part. Place only Ubuntu/Linux part here.

Comment: Removed windows part in subject. I don't think its the same issue as this pertains to viewing the list of wireless networks, which I want to view within my LAN. I don't want users to be distracted with other networks showing up on this list.

Comment: So basically, you do not want any auto-detection of WiFi networks and users cannot connect to any networks except the `ground-floor-c1` and `first-floor-c2` even when at home and at hotels and anywhere else in the world, right???  (Sounds like a bad idea to me, but just want to point out the obvious, because that *is* possible)

Comment: These machines are in the office and wouldn't move out of this building, so how do I restrict this to the wireless networks in my building alone. I want auto-detection to work only within my building, how should I enforce this?